# How to have the same component on different routes in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a sidebar component that I want to display on different pages in my Next js project. Of course I could just add it to every page separately, say for example I want my sidebar on `page1` and `page2` I add them to `page1.js` and `page2.js` in my `pages` folder. But when I navigate from `page1` to `page2` my sidebar component will reload and my useStates will be lost.

Ideally, I want to have some sort of template, say `_page_with_sidebar.js` where I can add my sidebar component and some sort of main component into which specific pages are rendered. This would be similar to the [custom document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) which Next js provides, but with scoping it to specific pages only.

Is this possible in Next js or is there even a better solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm not able to explain how it works so this isn't really an answer but what you're looking for is this [layout](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts) . If you go here and read through this and look at the example repo they provide you'll have all the info you need.

Comment: You are right! Layouts look promising. I will try to implement it. Thanks a lot.